# Conditional Formatting doesn't recognize timestamp?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

i am using a code for timestamp [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897736/20590728) here.

The issue is when i am trying to condtional format the row base on date i.e today it isnt working **=$A1=today()** what might be the issue

**Conditional Formatting doesn't recognize timestamp?**

you can find the sample sheet here [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUI-Gl7HDNGg5V2wM4ossUn46cp7VHRBZ_t4la2gDH0/edit#gid=1165350959)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates are calculated as a counting from 30/12/1899. For example, 29/12/2022 is expressed as 44924:

[image]

The hours, minutes and seconds are expressed as a fraction of a day:

[image]

So, as suggested you should keep the INT part or ROUNDDOWN the value of the TIMESTAMP in order to match TODAY's date (that is an integer without decimals):

```
=INT($A1)=TODAY()
=ROUNDDOWN($A1)=TODAY()
```

Comment: how about if i want to highlight week old data,
will **=INT($A1)=today()-7** work?

Comment: If you want to highlight that specific day, you can use that formula. If you want to highlight the whole last week? You can do =AND(INT($A1)>=(TODAY()-7),(INT($A1)<=TODAY())

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
=INT($A1)=today()
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=($A1*1<=TODAY()+1)*($A1*1>TODAY()-1)
```

or:

```
=INT($A1)=TODAY()
```

and see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201717/5632629

timestamp upon range edit:

```
=LAMBDA(x; x)(IFERROR(B1:1/0)+NOW())
```